# Why is wget still failing even after enclosing the URL with double quotes?

Tags: shell, quoting, filenames

I enclose URLs I want to `wget` with `""` since most of them have spaces, braces, etc. It usually works fine, but I can't get this URL to work:

```
wget "http://xxxx/Sankarea - 6 - It`s Because I... Ran Into You (720p-100MB)[Commie][Daylighter].mkv"
```

it outputs

```
-bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: command substitution: line 1: `s Because I... Ran Into You (720p-100MB)[Commie][Daylighter].mkv"
```

What does it mean? Is there any trick to solve this?

Comment: Backticks are used for command substitution, e.g. `echo "hello \`echo world\`"`.  Try single quotes.

Comment: thanks will try that, btw what if the file name has both `single quote` and `backtick` at its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try single quotes:

```
wget 'http://xxxx/Sankarea - 6 - It`s Because I... Ran Into You (720p-100MB)[Commie][Daylighter].mkv'
```

and if you would have a single quote in the URL itself then split the URL in two strings and insert the single quote with a backslash: `'...'\''....'` or using double quotes: `'...'"'"'....'`. Leave no spaces between these strings.

```
$ echo 'Haru'\''s Death'
Haru's Death
$ echo 'Haru'"'"'s Death'
Haru's Death
```

**No** characters are interpreted between the single quotes, not even the backslash (so you can't do `echo 'Haru\'s Death'`, that will get you the `PS2` prompt (normally `>`)

Comment: is this correct? http://pastebin.com/K4RtE0em

Comment: @TheWolf No! Every single `'` becomes `'\''`. Thus `Haru's Death` → `'Haru'\''s Death'` (or `'Haru'"'"'s Death'` that works as well to get the single quote)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, within "..." you can disable with backslash the characters shell still obeys; they are backslash itself `\` doublequote `"` dollar `$` backtick ` and (if shell supports history expansion and it isn't disabled) bang `!`. But (I agree) the singlequote approach is probably better here.